# Connecting Java/Android to .NET webservice

Tags: c#, java, android, .net, web-services

I've just build an .net default webservice with HelloWorld Method!

Now I'm trying to connect a Java/Android simple implementation to connect with .net webservice. I'm stuck on HttpTransportSE call. It doesn't work, actually it stops here. With ho no error.

Here the code sample:

```
private class SoapAccessTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  protected String doInBackground(String... urls){
     final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
     final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org";
     final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld;
     final String URL = "http://localhost:2986/Service1.asmx;

     SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
     SoapSerializationEnvelop envelop = new SoapSerializationEnvelop(SoapEnvelop.VER11);
     AndroidHttpTransport androidHttp = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
     androidHttp.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelop);
  }
}
```

Any idea why this is not working?

Regards

Comment: i m not getting what ur issue

Comment: The execution stucks on the invocation of androidHttp.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelop). I've tried to print something after this invocation and it is never called.

Comment: try catch and get the error.

Comment: Should I change tempuri.org to localhost?

Comment: try hosting it if possible, and also see my below answer, first try to do it without asynctask , also see my code below
;;
if you are not using android-ksoap2, try to connect using that android-ksoap2 and my code

Answer (score 1):

Put following lines in your code:

```
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

**EDIT:**

1. The dotNet flag needs to be true for a .NET web service call from kSOAP2 (As you are using .NET web service). Hence `envelope.dotNet = true;`
2. In the end SoapObject instance “request” is assigned as the outbound message of the soap call to the envelope. Hence `envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);`

Answer (score 0):

this code might be of help to you if you are using ksoap2 to access an asmx web method

```
public class ServiceHandler {
    private static String SOAP_ACTION;    
    private static String OPERATION_NAME;    
    private static final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://xxx.example.com/";    
    private static final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://xxx.example.com/WebService.asmx";

    /**
     * call WebMethod
     * 
     * @param param1 
     * @param param2 
     * 
     * @return //sample code
     */
    public static String callWebMethod(String param1,String param2){

        OPERATION_NAME = "myFunc";
        SOAP_ACTION = "http://xxx.example.com/myFunc";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

        request.addProperty("param1",param1);
        request.addProperty("param2",param2);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);

        try{                  
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);      
            SoapObject object = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            //get object
        }catch(Exception exception){
            System.out.println(exception.toString());
            return "";          
        }
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Ok, try/catch error is org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/} Envelope (position: START_TAG <html>@2.44 in java.io.InputStreamReader.

Comment: above code is a sample code you need to modify it to match your requirements and since this solution fix your problem of getting stuck at HttpTransportSE you may accept my answer

Comment: Yes, I have a similar implementation but using AsyncTask and the webservice method doesn't receive any arguments. This is the only differences.

Comment: host the web service and try to access it